# How do I write a cron job that will create a twilio message once

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron, twilio

I am trying to have my application get data from my firestore and create messages with that data. I currently have a cron job running every minute to check the firestore and create messages with the data in the db. But, the problem is it creates the same messages multiple times since it runs every minute. I tried not running every minute and just creating the messages when the app loads but the problem with that is if the user created a new message on the site it won't register with the app because the app only fetches from the db once. How can I fix this issue with the multiple messages?

Link: https://reminder-me-website.herokuapp.com/

```
require('dotenv').config() 
const path = require('path');
const twilio = require('twilio')
const client = twilio(
  process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_KEY)

const cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
  
const firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/firestore");

var config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: "reminder-app-4be61.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://reminder-app-4be61.firebaseio.com/",
  projectId: "reminder-app-4be61",
  storageBucket: "reminder-app-4be61.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "830815988398",
  appId: "1:830815988398:web:597257d987ea63668a9b3f",
  measurementId: "G-T600ZD0201",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();

const timeFactory = (hour, midday) =>{
  if(midday === 'AM' && hour === '12') {
    hour = '00'
  }
  else if(midday === 'PM' && hour === '12') {
    hour = '12'
  }
  else if(midday === 'PM' && Number(hour) < 12) {
    hour = Number(hour) + 12
  }
  else if(midday === 'AM' && Number(hour) < 12) {
    if(hour[0] === '0') {
      hour = 0 + Number(hour)
      hour = '0' + String(hour)
    } else {
      hour = 0 + Number(hour)
    }
  }
  return String(hour)
}
const setReminderFrequency = (freq, date, id) => {
  if('Once' === freq) {
    let dayOfTheWeek = new Date(date)
    let day = dayOfTheWeek.getDay()
    let dayOfTheMonth = date.slice(4, 6)
    let monthOfTheYear = date.slice(0, 3)
    db.collection('reminders').doc(id).delete()
    return [dayOfTheMonth, monthOfTheYear, String('0' + day)]
  }
  else if('Daily' === freq) {
    return ['*', '*', '*']
  }
  else if('Weekly' === freq) {
    let dayOfTheWeek = new Date(date)
    let day = dayOfTheWeek.getDay()
    return ['*', '*', String('0' + day)]
  }
  else if('Monthly' === freq) {
    let dayOfTheMonth = date.slice(4, 6)
   return [dayOfTheMonth, '*', '*']
  }
  else if('Yearly' === freq) {
    let monthOfTheYear = date.slice(0, 3)
    return ['*', monthOfTheYear, '*']
  }
}
new cronJob('* * * * *', () => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const numbers = [];
    const data = await db.collection('reminders').get()
    data.docs.map( doc => numbers.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
    for (let reminder of numbers) {
      let timeframe = reminder.time.slice(6, 8);
      let minute = reminder.time.slice(3, 5);
      let hour = reminder.time.slice(0, 2);
      hour = timeFactory(hour, timeframe);
      let frequency = setReminderFrequency(
        reminder.frequency,
        reminder.date,
        reminder.id
      );
      var textJob = new cronJob(
        `${minute} ${hour} ${frequency[0]} ${frequency[1]} ${frequency[2]}`,
        () => {
          client.messages.create(
            {
              to: reminder.phoneNumber,
              from: "4104691056",//Why "Reminder Me" id dont work?
              body: reminder.message,
            },
            (err, message) => {
              console.log(message.body, err)
            }
          );
        },
        null,
        true, reminder.timezone
      );
    }
    
  }
  fetchData()
}, null, true)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});


  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
  });
```

Comment: you probably want to mark off the record when its processed so you dont recreate the same message

Comment: Mark off the record?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion phrase, I mean store an indication that the message was sent for that particular record. This way you can run it continuously without duplicate messages